# Iterate over matrices in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

How can you iterate over all 2^(n^2) binary n by n matrices (or 2d arrays) in numpy? I would something like:

```
for M in ....:
```

Do you have to use `itertools.product([0,1], repeat = n**2)` and then convert to a 2d numpy array?

This code will give me a random 2d binary matrix but that isn't what I need.

```
np.random.randint(2, size=(n,n))
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Numpy is vectorized, so for many operations you don't need to explicitly iterate.

Comment: @MattDMo I want to run a test on each 2d binary n by n matrix. n will be very small so this should be doable.

Comment: How big n can be? are you aware of 2**(n**2) growth rate?

Comment: @alko Even n=4 would be a great start.

Comment: Are you working with a 2d (nxn) array of objects, each of which is a matrix (or 2d array), or a 4d array (`shape=(n,n,m,m)`)?  What's the 'dtype`?  The nxn dimensions can be reduced to 1d with reshape or `flatten()` (or `ravel`).

Comment: @hpaulj I would just like to iterate over all 2d binary arrays and run a function on each one.  I suppose you could call this a 1d array of 2d arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `2**(n**2)` is a big number for even relatively small n, so your loop might run indefinetely long.

Being said that, one possible way to iterate matrices you need is for example

```
nxn = np.arange(n**2).reshape(n, -1)
for i in xrange(0, 2**(n**2)):
    arr = (i >> nxn) % 2
    # do smthng with arr
```

Comment: Nice! It's probably faster to do `& 1` instead of `% 2`, though. Also, if `nxn` is a multiple of 8, it may be faster to call [`np.unpackbits`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
np.array(list(itertools.product([0,1], repeat = n**2))).reshape(-1,n,n)
```

produces a `(2^(n^2),n,n)` array.

There may be some numpy 'grid' function that does the same, but my recollection from other discussions is that `itertools.product` is pretty fast.

```
g=(np.array(x).reshape(n,n) for x in itertools.product([0,1], repeat = n**2))
```

is a generator that produces the nxn arrays one at time:

```
g.next()
# array([[0, 0],[0, 0]])
```

Or to produce the same 3d array:

```
np.array(list(g))
```